# Why is this Zener across the collector and emitter of this transistor driving a solenoid coil?

Tags: circuit-analysis, zener, solenoid, vintage

I am trying to understand a vintage (1970s) impact printer circuit. Each of the pins in the printer are driven by a small individual coil driver circuit, that was originally specified to look like this:

[image]

*(Detail from a schematic [here.](https://deramp.com/swtpc.com/PR_40/PR40_Schematic.pdf) )*

I understand how this works since [I asked a question about it earlier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/706049/why-is-this-zener-in-series-at-the-base-of-transistor-and-has-something-failed) and got some great answers, but the company that sold the printer issued an addendum to the circuit with an update, where a 62V Zener diode (1N4759) is added from the collector to the emitter:

[image]

(SWTPC PR-40 addendum detail.)

What is the purpose of this additional diode?

I'm assuming it's to protect something (the coil?), since it was an after-the-fact addition to the circuit design, but I'm having a hard time intuiting what's happening here.

I don't think the Zener will do anything in normal operation-- the 40VDC rail is below the 62V breakdown voltage so it won't bypass the transistor. Is this a protection for if the 40V rail somehow manages to jump up to > 62V? Is something else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there because the coil has *inductance*. When the transistor tries to turn off the inductance fights against the dying of the current by changing voltage in the direction that tends to maintain the current as much as possible. That means it goes from about +40V to 0V and continues to go negative until something  stops it. That something could be the transistor breaking down (which is very hard on the transistor and could  certainly affect reliability) or it could be something across the coil or the transistor conducting. Or it could just resonate with the coil distributed capacitance and ring for a while if the transistor has a high enough breakdown voltage (it might be hundreds of volts though).

If we didn't give a toss about speed we would just slap a (normally reverse-biased) diode across the coil and the Vce of that transistor would be limited to maybe -41V, since the coil voltage would only go to one diode drop below ground. Easy and cheap. But that's a bad solution if we want the maximum speed since the current will continue for longer that if we allow the voltage across the transistor to get higher, perhaps to -62V by using Zener diode.

That's harder on the transistor, but not as hard as letting the transistor absorb the energy that now goes into the Zener diode.
The total energy in the coil is \$ L I^2/2\$, and the initial current will be the coil current when on. Some of the energy goes into the coil resistance, some into the Zener diode, and some goes into the transistor as it is trying to switch off.

The transistor will have a specification called SOA (Safe Operating Area) that indicates the allowable current and voltage that transistor can reliably handle.

Comment: The other [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/706049/101063) says the transistor used in the printer is a ``TIP127``. The [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/TIP127-890152.pdf) for a TIP127 shows it is a darlington with an internal diode between the collector and emitter. Is the external zener to allow a quicker turn off for the solenoid as suggested is this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/26948/101063)?

Comment: @ChesterGillon The internal 'diode' between collector and emitter will do nothing to help with the inductance. It will stay reverse-biased as the transistor breaks down. Unless, of course, it was designed to be a Zener diode itself, and there is no indication of that. The added Zener diode protects the transistor at the expense of some speed, but not as much as a diode right across the coil would.

Comment: Thank you for the detail. It seems like the original design (without the zener) allowed the field to collapse most quickly but exposed the transistor's collector fully to the voltage change that resulted. It sounds like this was actually an inadvisable design (versus something to add extra protection to). You've clarified why you choose a zener vs a normal diode across the coil itself, but a dumb followup: why doesn't the dissipating field current go to ground? Why are we channeling it back to the 40V rail (or are we not)? Thanks

Comment: Either way would work. Might just be it was an easier retrofit for the fix.

Comment: You can't do the zener trick to ground because it would be forward biased under normal operation. You would need 2 diodes in series to pull that off.

Comment: @MOSFET Yes. Or a bipolar TVS, but they may not have been available in that era.

Answer (score 1):

> *My question is: what is the purpose of this additional diode?*

It's to protect the transistor from excessive back-emfs when it tries to deactivate the solenoid, Energy gained in the magnetic field of the solenoid has to be released and, to avoid an excessively high voltage being generated, the Zener diode provides a path to safely discharge that energy.

This sort of thing is normally achieved using a diode directly across the solenoid but, if you want to deactivate the solenoid quickly, you need to burn off that stored energy at a higher rate than a simple diode achieves so, the Zener diode allows the collector to fall 62 volts below its emitter. The transistor has to be rated to withstand probably 80 volts or more for this to be reliable.